# Getting Mockito error: "Wanted but not invoked... actually, there were zero interactions with this mock"

Tags: java, android, testing, mockito

I'm getting the above error whilst running my unit test for a java class in an Android project (in Android Studio).

The class under test:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import **.CustomObject;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class CustomClass {
  private static final String string = "a";
  private static CustomObject customObject = null;
  private static CountDownLatch initializedLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

  @NonNull
  public static CustomObject1 getCustomObject1() {
      try {
          initializedLatch.await();
          assert customObject != null;
          return customObject;

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(".");
      }
  }

  public static void methodA(final Context context,
                                         final String string1,
                                         ) throws exception {
      initializedLatch.countDown();
  }


  public static void methodB(@NonNull final CustomObject customObjectInput) {
      customObject = customObjectInput;
  }
}
```

The test class:

```
import android.content.Context;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import **.CustomObject;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomClassTest{

    @Mock
    static CustomObject customObject;

    @Mock
    static Context context;

    @Mock
    CountDownLatch mCountDownLatch;

    @Mock
    CountDownLatch mInitializedLatch;

    @InjectMocks
    CustomClass customClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        customObject = Mockito.spy(CustomObject.class);
        context = Mockito.spy(Context.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void customClassTest() {

        doNothing().when(mInitializedLatch).countDown();

        CustomClass.methodB(customObject);
        try {
            CustomClass.methodA(context, "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        verify(mInitializedLatch).countDown();

        try {
            doNothing().when(mInitializedLatch).await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Class.getCustomObject();
    }
```

The specific message I'm getting when running customClassTest:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mInitializedLatch.countDown();
-> at CustomClassTest.methodA(CustomClassTest.java:79)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
mInitializedLatch.countDown();
-> at CustomClassTest.methodA(CustomClassTest.java:79)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Running the debugger with break points at each of the relevant lines seems to suggest that the test runs fine (with all the variables being assigned correctly at the right points) until verify(mInitializedLatch).countDown();, when the message appears (and the code stops running).

Any help appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE #1:

Altered the code to remove static keyword:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import **.CustomObject;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class CustomClass {
  private final String string = "a";
  private CustomObject customObject = null;
  private CountDownLatch initializedLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

  @NonNull
  public CustomObject1 getCustomObject1() {
      try {
          initializedLatch.await();
          assert customObject != null;
          return customObject;

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(".");
      }
  }

  public void methodA(final Context context,
                                         final String string1,
                                         ) throws exception {
      initializedLatch.countDown();
  }


  public void methodB(@NonNull final CustomObject customObjectInput) {
      customObject = customObjectInput;
  }
}
```

```
import android.content.Context;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import **.CustomObject;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomClassTest{

    @Mock
    CustomObject customObject;

    @Mock
    Context context;

    @Mock
    CountDownLatch mCountDownLatch;

    @Mock
    CountDownLatch mInitializedLatch;

    @InjectMocks
    CustomClass customClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        customObject = Mockito.spy(CustomObject.class);
        context = Mockito.spy(Context.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void customClassTest() {

        doNothing().when(mInitializedLatch).countDown();

        customClass.methodB(customObject);
        try {
            customClass.methodA(context, "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        verify(mInitializedLatch).countDown();

        try {
            doNothing().when(mInitializedLatch).await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        customClass.getCustomObject();
    }
```

Error messages now read:

```
error: non-static method methodA(Context,String) cannot be referenced from a static context
error: non-static method getCustomObject1() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

The second error message is displayed six times. It seems the code isn't compiling.

Answer (score 0):

In CustomClass the CountDownLatch is declared as static field and it's initialized. If you debug your class you can see Mockito is not mocking/proxing this field. All the code interaction to initializedLatch object are not intercepted by Mockito proxy, so when you set-up your test by doNothing().when(mInitializedLatch).countDown(), actually you're not setting the field into customClass.So when you use verify(mInitializedLatch).countDown(), you're actually saying to Mockito that you expect one interaction with this mock, but no interactions are made due the reason above.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting no invocations because the actual call is not made with your mocked **mInitializedLatch** object.

While mocking any object, you need to tell the compiler to use this mocked object instead of the one indeed present in your source implementation.

This can be achieved by making the object you are looking to test as an instance variable and passing the mocked object in the constructor.
Then the calls will be made from your mocked object and mockito will be able to track those.

Example:

```
// Source Code
public class CustomerClass {
    private final CountDownLatch initializedLatch

    public CustomerClass(CountDownLatch initializedLatch) {
        this.initializedLatch = initializedLatch;
    }
}
```

Now, use this instance variable in your code instead of the static variable you defined.

In test code, create constructor of CustomerClass by passing the mocked initializedLatch object and then it will work like charm.

> If you are looking to initialize the value of initializedLatch there only. You can do the same by keeping a default constructor alongside the constructor I have defined above.

This default constructor can call the parameterized constructor.

```
public CustomerClass() {
    this(new CountDownLatch(1));
}
```

---

Edit:

You also need to change your source implementation.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import **.CustomObject;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class CustomClass {
  private static final String string = "a";
  private CustomObject customObject;
  private CountDownLatch initializedLatch;

  public CustomClass() {
    this(new CountDownLatch(1), null);
  }

  public CustomClass(CountDownLatch initializedLatch, CustomObject customObject) {
    this.initializedLatch = initializedLatch;
    this.customObject = customObject;
  }

  @NonNull
  public CustomObject1 getCustomObject1() {
      try {
          initializedLatch.await();
          assert customObject != null;
          return customObject;

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(".");
      }
  }

  public void methodA(final Context context final String string1) throws Exception {
      initializedLatch.countDown();
  }


  public void methodB(@NonNull final CustomObject customObjectInput) {
      customObject = customObjectInput;
  }
}
```

Now, above source implementation will use **initializedLatch** and **customObject** provided in the constructor.

Test code

```
import android.content.Context;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import **.CustomObject;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomClassTest{

    @Mock
    CustomObject customObject;

    @Mock
    Context context;

    @Mock
    CountDownLatch mInitializedLatch;

    @InjectMocks
    CustomClass customClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        customClass = new CustomClass(mInitializedLatch, customObject);
    }

    @Test
    public void customClassTest() {

        doNothing().when(mInitializedLatch).countDown();

        customClass.methodB(customObject);
        try {
            customClass.methodA(context, "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        verify(mInitializedLatch).countDown();

        try {
            doNothing().when(mInitializedLatch).await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        customClass.getCustomObject();
    }
```

> Regarding the error you are getting, I don't think that's because of
>   the call you are making from the tests.

Comment: Thanks- I've added the constructors but now it's not compiling because I can't call initializedLatch.countDown() from a static context. I changed the method to non-static but that messes up CustomClass.methodA(context, "") in the test class because methodA is  non static, so I changed all the references of CustomClass to customClass. Now I'm still getting a message saying that methodA and getCustomObject1 cannot be referenced from a static context, but I can't see why that's the case given that there are no usages of static keyword other than the imports of doNothing() and verify(). Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for delay. I've put the updated code and error messages as an update edit, please see above. Thanks.

Comment: Think I've figured out the issue. It seems that there are other classes in my project that are referencing this one which are still referencing it from a static context. Will update those first.

Comment: I have added the code snippet which may work for you.